# Laravel: Trying to access value inside array in view template

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

So I'm trying to access the value of a few pair of `key->values` inside an array I create and pass to the view called config, I'd like to access to them like this : `{{ $config->web_name['value'] }}` or `{{ $config->$web_name['value'] }}` but both are returning errors.

This is how I pass the data to my view:

```
public function inicio()
    {

        $pageInfo = 
        [
            'page_title'      => 'Inicio',
            'menu_active'     => 'Inicio',
            'submenu_active' => '',
        ];

        $globals = Globals::all();

        $web_name = $globals->where('name', 'Nombre del restaurante')->first();
        $web_description = $globals->where('name', 'Descripcion en google del restaurante')->first();
        $restaurant_bio = $globals->where('name', 'Biografia del restaurante')->first();
        $booking_phone = $globals->where('name', 'Télefono de reserva')->first();
        $client_mail = $globals->where('name', 'Email de contacto')->first();
        $full_address = $globals->where('name', 'Dirección del restaurante')->first();
        $city_zip_address = $globals->where('name', 'Código postal y ciudad')->first();

        $config = compact('web_name', 'web_description');

        $sliders = Slider::all();


        return view('inicio.index', compact('pageInfo', 'config', 'sliders', 'web_name'));
    }
```

Comment: Paste the errors detail

Comment: Trying to get property 'web_name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Restaurante1\resources\views\inicio\index.blade.php)

Comment: Your $config isn't object. It's array. Read the error a little bit, it explains it very good.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use variables passed to your views like objects, but when you [do](https://www.quora.com/What-does-compact-do-in-Laravel) `compact()` you are making them `arrays`. So to access your data do something like this:

```
{{ $config['web_name']['value'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Also, you are compacting $web_name twice.

```
{{$web_name['value']}}
```